# Change button appearance when focus or click?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a button with background image.

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="5px" 
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
 android:id="@+id/button1" 
 android:background="@drawable/imagename">
</Button>
```

I wanna make it would be different (shadow, brightness etc...) when user click or touches on the button.

You know standard buttons are changed color when focused or clicked. 
I am trying to make like this.

How to make it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a selector XML and specify that as button background. To get an idea of how this works check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton) out.

Answer (score 5):

For that you have to create custom drawable with different state of the button. First got to res->drawable and right click and add new drawable file. Name it as button_default. Add following code to that file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default_click" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default_click" android:state_focused="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default_click" android:state_active="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default_normal" />
</selector>
```

In this file we have defined the drawable need to use when tigger different state of the button.
Now got drawable folder and create a new drawable called button_default_click and add following code to that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:startColor="@color/gray_light"
        android:type="linear" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/gray_dark" />
</shape>
```

you can change these color properties what ever color you like.
Now create a another drawable called button_default_normal. This is the drawable which use there are no any triggers. Add following code to that.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/gray_light_300" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:startColor="@color/gray_light"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

No we have to assign the created selector drawable to the button.

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="5px" 
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
 android:id="@+id/button1" 
 android:background="@drawable/button_default.xml">
</Button>
```